# Show that if $A_{\alpha}$ is closed in $X_{α}$, then $\prod A_\alpha$ is closed in $\prod X_\alpha$

Tags: general-topology, product-space

> Show that if $A_{\alpha}$ is closed in $X_{α}$, then $\prod A_\alpha$ is closed in $\prod X_\alpha$.

Please could you help me?
I have no idea how to do it.
I appreciate any help, hint or solution.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: HInt: consider first the case in which for all but one $\alpha$ you have $A_\alpha=X_\alpha$

Comment: We have $$\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha^c\times \prod_{\beta \neq \alpha} X_\beta =(\prod_\alpha A_\alpha)^c.$$

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I got it, thank you very much.
I love u

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

The projections $p_\alpha: \prod_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha \to X_\alpha$ are all continuous and so

$$\prod_{\alpha \in A} A_\alpha = \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} p_\alpha^{-1}[A_\alpha]$$

is an intersection of closed sets in $\prod_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ and hence closed too.